# Disable Horizontal Scrolling in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to do this?  I'd much rather have the code wrap and say within 80-100 character line lengths.  The scroll over every time I swipe is driving me crazy!

Comment: Does activating `View | Active Editor | Use Soft Wraps` works for you?

Comment: Please convert your comment into an answer so I can give you the points. Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is **"soft wraps"** functionality in IDE -- it does just that -- it virtually (on a screen only) breaks the line into multiple to show whole line without the need for horizontal scrolling.

It can be enabled at:

- **For all files:** `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General |Soft-wrap these files`
- **For current file only:** `View | Active Editor | Use Soft Wraps`

These options are also available via gutter context menu (the area where the line numbers are). If you have customized that context menu long time ago ... then they may not be there (as they were added there straight away).

[image]

Comment: How to disable horizontal scrolling in the files sidebar?

Comment: I couldn't find the All files setting in the latest build as of this comment, but I did find the setting for the current file.

Comment: @ShawnW Check the screenshot.