# How to make IntelliJ formatter break long lines automatically while typing?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, intellisense, jetbrains-ide

I want the formatter to break the line when the code reaches the right margin.

I found solution, but for older versions of IntelliJ.
How can I do this in IntelliJ 2018?

Example:

[image: first image]

and then when I type `toLowerCase`, for example - 
to receive that:
[image: second image]

Comment: give an example of line you want to formatt and expecten result

Comment: That doesn't matter. I mean I want it to do it on every line. If I use autocompletion and the space to the right margin is not enough the line to be breaked.

Comment: You go to settings > editor > code style > java > wrapping and braces. You can set where the editor should break the lines there and how

Comment: I checked there. There's nothing like that. Only hard wrap. When I turn "Wrap on typing" it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Based on your second screenshot .. it's just a soft-wrap: the code is still on a single line but instead of horizontal scrolling the text is displayed on multiple lines (soft wrapped). Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310682/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649137/783119

Comment: @LazyOne Yes. Actually this is soft-wrap and I make it to works.Thank you. But still can't set the wrap on typing to work.

Comment: It's all automatic -- use the first link to see if it's enabled for current file or not. You can then enable/disable for each file (has to be applied every time you open it) .. or enable/disable for all files by default. My first link has what to look for and where (answers are old .. but you can use search field and type  `soft warp` there to narrow it)

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java*, switch to *Wrapping and Braces* tab and change *Wrap on typing* to *Yes*.

[image]